# Vue: Using Vuetify library scoped to component?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I am using Vuetify only for nested Vue app inside a larger Laravel app.  However, the Vuetify.js created stylesheets that effect all the styles from the base level of the app, where all the Laravel and Laravel styles were -- it's overriding them.  I am not sure how to 'scope' it since it's the Vuetify.js script that is dynamically creating the stylesheets.